# Trying to remove a RecycleView item(Loaded from webservices) by swiping left or right

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I was trying to remove a particular listitem of a recyclerview which is loaded the data from Url.

Here is my MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String responseFromServer;
    Button btnGetData;
    RecyclerView rView;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnGetData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGetData);
        rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rVIew);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        rView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               refreshAdapter();
            }
        });

    }
    class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            WebMethods methods = new WebMethods();
            responseFromServer = methods.getData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            setOutData(responseFromServer);
        }
    }
    public void setOutData(String  response)
    {
        ParserClass parserClass = new ParserClass();
        ArrayList<PlacesData> data = parserClass.getData(response);
        final MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this,data);
        rView.setAdapter(adapter);


        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                rView.removeViewAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
               // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             //   adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
               //adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
               // adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());



            }
        });
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rView);
    }
    public void refreshAdapter()
    {
        PlacesTask task = new PlacesTask();
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

and my Adapter class is

MyRecyclerAdapter.java

```
    public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecycler> {
    MainActivity activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<PlacesData> data;
    public MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity activity,ArrayList<PlacesData> data)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this.activity =activity;
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public MyRecycler onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleitem,null);
        MyRecycler recycler = new MyRecycler(view);
        return recycler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecycler holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvRating.setText(data.get(position).getRating());
        Picasso.with(activity).load(data.get(position).getIcon()).into(holder.imgIcon);
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                data.remove(data.get(position));
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

While using the delete button it is working fine but by swiping it is not working it is showing empty space and the adapter is not updating properly.

I am new this swipe deletion process i was learning it so suggest me possible changes or suggest me any best approach to do this
[image: The empty space is showing by swiping]

I have swiped two list items but the space is showing.. i have tried all

```
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

Comment: i did not try this.but i think you can handle this with onTouchListener method within your adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Data from `ArrayList` inside `onMove()`. The use `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
       // rView.removeViewAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); //Optional .Since we uses notifyDataSetChanged()
        data.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

       // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     //   adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

        return false;
    }
```

use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rView)`

please try this. Happy Coding

Comment: I have tried but how can i use data.remove(....) in MainActivity i can apply it on Recyclerview only... I have changed MainActivity as you suggested but no change

Comment: data removed successfully but the list is showing empty spaces help me for that...

Comment: Did u use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: yes... Before i post the question i had tried all the 3 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()); in both onMove() and onSwiped()

Comment: if not working itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rView); try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  after this step

Comment: after removing that particular row u have to notify the adapter for notifying data changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158934/discussion-between-tomin-b-and-durgaprasad-kalapati).

Comment: Happy Coding Dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Please change below code in onSwiped method.

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
     adapter.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
     list.remove(position);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: how can i use list.remove(position) in MainActivity i have apply it to recyclerview

Comment: Use data.remove(position);

Comment: data removed successfully but the list is showing empty spaces help me for that...

Answer (score 1):

```
By These Changes I got the solution

 ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            data.remove(data.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




        }
    });
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rView);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thanks for your support